# Label wrapping and editable

Tags: codenameone, label

How do you make Labels wrap like Span Labels, but also be inline with following Labels so things look right?

Also, how can you make the Labels editable on click/touch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a BoxLayout Y to align them to the left together.

If you want a text area to look like a label do:

```
TextArea t = new TextArea();
t.setUIID("Label");
```

Comment: This is more what I'm trying to do -> ( http://i903.photobucket.com/albums/ac231/yanike5/labels_zpsh7urgwht.png ) Can this be done with the labels and text areas text wrapping and being inline with the following labels and text areas.

Comment: I have no idea what that image is showing. You can set the UIID on a text area to anything and customize that UIID to look like anything you want

Comment: What I'm trying to do is have the labels, text area, etc. wrap together and stay inline like texts, links, and images do in a Rich Text Editor.

Comment: Basically like a run-in or inline style https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/d/display/#run-in

Comment: We have this https://www.codenameone.com/blog/tip-lightweight-rich-text-view.html but it's not for editing dynamically. You can have individual elements editable but not the whole thing as you type. Not sure if that's what you are looking for.